# Why will some code execute while others won't?

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
   scroll: function()
 { 
 console.log( "scrolling..." ); 
 this.blockPlacementEnabled = false
 setTimeout(function() 
  {
   console.log("hello");
   this.blockPlacementEnabled = true 
  }, 200);

 },
```

the function runs perfectly and without errors, however once it gets to

> this.blockPlacementEnabled = true

that line refuses to run and instead the code continues as if i hadn't called the line
why is it that some functions run while others will not from a delay?

Comment: What browser, ie does not HAVE a console, and that line of code ( `console.log("hello");` ) will case a error, and cause that code snippit to terminate. And if its being run asynchrounously you wont see an error.

Comment: the entire project or the entire of that specific file?

Comment: what is blockPlacementEnabled

Comment: Inside the `setTimeout` callback, `this` refers to `window`.

Comment: `this` in the setTimeout is not the calling instance; `var self = this;` and use `self` instead of `this` in `setTimeout()`

Comment: works pretty much unchanged in jsfiddle on chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/FXKmG/

Comment: @PaulProgrammer: Only works because of how you set up the code. In both cases `this` refers to `window`.

Comment: should i post the full class ?

Comment: scroll: function()
   { 
   var self = this;
   console.log( "scrolling..." ); 
   this.blockPlacementEnabled = false
   setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("hello");
  self.blockPlacementEnabled = true 
}, 200);
  
   }, also isnt working. no errors tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `setTimeout` callback, `this` refers to `window`, not to the object it refers to in `scroll`. This means that `blockPlacementEnabled` is never set to `true` in your object.

Keep a reference to the object:

```
scroll: function() { 
  console.log( "scrolling..." ); 
  this.blockPlacementEnabled = false;

  var self = this; // reference to the current object
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("hello");
    self.blockPlacementEnabled = true; // referencing the current object
  }, 200);
},
```

or use [`.bind` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

[Learn more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

You've put that line in a `setTimeout`, which is asynchonous. The code will continue to execute in the normal control flow (top to bottom) and after 200 ms, `this.blockPlacementEnabled = true` will be executed.

Also as some of the commenters pointed out, `this` refers to the window in `setTimeout`, so you'll need to keep a reference to this and use that in your set timeout function:

```
scroll: function()
{ 
     var that = this;
     console.log( "scrolling..." ); 
     that.blockPlacementEnabled = false; //<HERE

     setTimeout(function() 
     {
       console.log("hello");
       that.blockPlacementEnabled = true; //<HERE
     }, 200);
},
```